# Running an ACL script to add security groups, but how do I skip child items?

Tags: powershell

I want to add some security groups, but I want to skip all files and folders under a folder that has inheritance disabled.

```
# Get all the items in the current directory
$items = Get-ChildItem \\server\file\share -Recurse

# Loop through each item and add the groups if inheritance is enabled
foreach ($item in $items) {
    $acl = Get-Acl $item.FullName
    if ($acl.AreAccessRulesProtected) {
        Write-Host "Skipping item $($item.FullName) because inheritance is disabled."
        continue
    }
    # If inheritance is not disabled add the following groups to files/folders
    else {
        $accessRule1 = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("domain\group-FC", "FullControl", "Allow")
        $accessRule2 = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("domain\group-Home-RO", "ReadAndExecute", "Allow")
        $accessRule3 = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("domain\group-Home-RW", "Modify", "Allow")
        $acl.addAccessRule($accessRule1)
        $acl.addAccessRule($accessRule2)
        $acl.addAccessRule($accessRule3)
        Set-Acl $item.FullName $acl
        Write-Host "Added groups to $($item.FullName)."
    }
}
```

I tried to use a continue and that didn't work. I asked chatgpt but it is dumb too.

Comment: Why do you need `continue`?  The `if(<condition>){<code>}else{<code>}` will only do one or the other, and then hit the end of that loop in the `foreach`, causing the next loop  in the `foreach` to start.  Is the code not working so you tried adding the `coninue`?

Comment: Honestly, this was a suggestion from chatgpt. I didn't think it would work. But tried it anyways.

Comment: And the code works. I just need it to go to the next if inheritance is disabled, instead of recurse that folder still.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding another "if" statement for checking inheritance.
Something like this:

```
$items = Get-ChildItem \\server\file\share -Recurse
foreach ($item in $items) {
    $acl = Get-Acl $item.FullName

    #...............
    # Your code here
    #...............

    if ($acl.Access.IsInherited -contains $true) {
        continue
    }
}
```

Note that on the "Access" property, there are multiple accesses.
You can also check if inheritance is enabled only for an identity reference.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I am a little confused.  If I add another "if" statement, but after my code, won't the ACLs be changed already?

Comment: Yes, what I meant is after any other check you need to do, but before changing it.